# How to config nginx to run flask and node

Tags: docker, nginx

Hi have a docker that builds my frontend(gatsby) and backend(flask) into a single docker file.
I can run my backend if i use my current config that only deploys the backend.
What i need is to deploy both backend and frontend.
I use supervisord to launch uwsgi and nginx.

My dockerfile tree:

```
---app
   ---backend
      ---dev_maintenance
         __init__.py
   ---frontend
      ---src
      ---node_modules
      ---public
```

nginx.conf

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    client_body_temp_path /spool/nginx/client_temp 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path /spool/nginx/fastcgi_temp 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path /spool/nginx/proxy_temp 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path /spool/nginx/scgi_temp 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path /spool/nginx/uwsgi_temp 1 2;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri @dev_maintenance;
        }
        location @dev_maintenance {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi.sock;
        }
        location /static {
            alias /opt/repo/src/static;
            expires 1d;
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying something like this:

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    client_body_temp_path /spool/nginx/client_temp 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path /spool/nginx/fastcgi_temp 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path /spool/nginx/proxy_temp 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path /spool/nginx/scgi_temp 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path /spool/nginx/uwsgi_temp 1 2;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass        http://client:3000;
            proxy_redirect    default;
            proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header  Host $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

          location /api {
            proxy_pass        http://api:5000;
            proxy_redirect    default;
            proxy_set_header  Host $host;
            proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          }
        location @dev_maintenance {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi.sock;
        }
        location /static {
            alias /opt/repo/src/static;
            expires 1d;
        }
    }
}
```

supervisord.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/run/supervisor.sock
chmod=0770

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
pidfile=/run/pid/supervisord.pid
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=1

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///run/supervisor.sock

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;" -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:uwsgi]
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/uwsgi.ini
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

uswgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
module= dev_maintenance:app
callable=app
buffer-size=65535
lazy=true
socket = /run/uwsgi.sock
```

Does not work of course , I'am new to this and it's confusing to learn it. any help?

Comment: Standard practice would be to run the nginx proxy and the Flask backend in separate containers; if your front-end application isn't compiled to static files, also run that in a third container.  Doing this will take the supervisor configuration out of the picture and make it easier to update only one part of the combined system.  The Docker documentation includes [several multi-container sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/#sample-applications).

Comment: yes i know but this time i need to do it like this

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed the problem, i needed to copy my frontend Gatsby build  that is generated in the docker when i run `npm run build` to the `/opt/repo/src/static` folder and change the `location /api` to:

```
location /api {

            try_files $uri @dev_maintenance;
        }
```